# Wix UI customization: Adding InstallScopeDlg to WixUI_Minimal

Tags: user-interface, wix, windows-installer, wix3.6

I am trying to add the `InstallScopeDlg` to my installer using Wix. Because `InstallScopeDlg` is only available in `WixUI_Advanced` but I don't need the other dialogs from that UI, I decided to create my own UI by copying `WixUI_Minimal` code and renaming to `WixUI_MyMinimal`. Then I changed some of the sequences and button names so I could put `InstallScopeDlg` after the `WelcomeEulaDlg` and before `ProgressDlg`. I also copied the other required dialogs to my Wix project in visual studio. 
The interface is shown correctly but the "Next" button on `InstallScopeDlg` does not work and shows the `ProgressDlg` without doing anything.

1 - Is this a correct solution to add the `InstallScopeDlg`?
2 - How can I fix this problem?

The following is the code for `WixUI_MyMinimal`

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<Fragment>
    <WixVariable Id="WixUISupportPerUser" Value="1" Overridable="yes" />
    <WixVariable Id="WixUISupportPerMachine" Value="1" Overridable="yes" />
    <PropertyRef Id="ApplicationFolderName" />

    <CustomAction Id="WixSetDefaultPerUserFolder" Property="WixPerUserFolder" Value="[LocalAppDataFolder]Apps\[ApplicationFolderName]" Execute="immediate" />
    <CustomAction Id="WixSetDefaultPerMachineFolder" Property="WixPerMachineFolder" Value="[ProgramFilesFolder][ApplicationFolderName]" Execute="immediate" />
    <CustomAction Id="WixSetPerUserFolder" Property="APPLICATIONFOLDER" Value="[WixPerUserFolder]" Execute="immediate" />
    <CustomAction Id="WixSetPerMachineFolder" Property="APPLICATIONFOLDER" Value="[WixPerMachineFolder]" Execute="immediate" />

    <InstallExecuteSequence>
        <Custom Action="WixSetDefaultPerUserFolder" Before="CostFinalize" />
        <Custom Action="WixSetDefaultPerMachineFolder" After="WixSetDefaultPerUserFolder" />
        <Custom Action="WixSetPerUserFolder" After="WixSetDefaultPerMachineFolder">ACTION="INSTALL" AND APPLICATIONFOLDER="" AND (ALLUSERS="" OR (ALLUSERS=2 AND (NOT Privileged)))</Custom>
        <Custom Action="WixSetPerMachineFolder" After="WixSetPerUserFolder">ACTION="INSTALL" AND APPLICATIONFOLDER="" AND (ALLUSERS=1 OR (ALLUSERS=2 AND Privileged))</Custom>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>


    <UI Id="WixUI_MyMinimal">
        <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Normal" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="8" />
        <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Bigger" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="12" />
        <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Title" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="9" Bold="yes" />

        <Property Id="DefaultUIFont" Value="WixUI_Font_Normal" />
        <Property Id="myWixUI_Mode" Value="InstallCustom" />

        <DialogRef Id="ErrorDlg" />
        <DialogRef Id="FatalError" />
        <DialogRef Id="FilesInUse" />
        <DialogRef Id="MsiRMFilesInUse" />
        <DialogRef Id="PrepareDlg" />
        <DialogRef Id="ProgressDlg" />
        <DialogRef Id="ResumeDlg" />
        <DialogRef Id="UserExit" />
        <DialogRef Id="WelcomeDlg" />
        <DialogRef Id="WelcomeEulaDlg" />
        <DialogRef Id="InstallScopeDlg"/>

        <Publish Dialog="ExitDialog" Control="Finish" Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" Order="999">1</Publish>

        <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Order="2">1</Publish>

        <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceWelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Order="2">1</Publish>

        <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="RepairButton" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg" Order="2">1</Publish>
        <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="RemoveButton" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg" Order="2">1</Publish>
        <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceWelcomeDlg" Order="2">1</Publish>

        <Publish Dialog="InstallScopeDlg" Control="Next" Property="WixAppFolder" Value="WixPerUserFolder" Order="1">!(wix.WixUISupportPerUser) AND NOT Privileged</Publish>
        <Publish Dialog="InstallScopeDlg" Control="Next" Property="ALLUSERS" Value="{}" Order="2">WixAppFolder = "WixPerUserFolder"</Publish>
        <Publish Dialog="InstallScopeDlg" Control="Next" Property="ALLUSERS" Value="1" Order="3">WixAppFolder = "WixPerMachineFolder"</Publish>
        <Publish Dialog="InstallScopeDlg" Control="Next" Property="APPLICATIONFOLDER" Value="[WixPerUserFolder]" Order="4">WixAppFolder = "WixPerUserFolder"</Publish>
        <Publish Dialog="InstallScopeDlg" Control="Next" Property="APPLICATIONFOLDER" Value="[WixPerMachineFolder]" Order="5">WixAppFolder = "WixPerMachineFolder"</Publish>
        <Publish Dialog="InstallScopeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="ProgressDlg" Order="6">WixAppFolder = "WixPerUserFolder"</Publish>
        <Publish Dialog="InstallScopeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="ProgressDlg" Order="7">WixAppFolder = "WixPerMachineFolder"</Publish>

        <Publish Dialog="InstallScopeDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="WelcomeEulaDlg" Order="2">1</Publish>

        <Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="WelcomeEulaDlg" Order="2">!(wix.WixUISupportPerMachine) AND !(wix.WixUISupportPerUser)</Publish>
        <Publish Dialog="WelcomeEulaDlg" Control="Install" Event="NewDialog" Value="InstallScopeDlg" Order="2">!(wix.WixUISupportPerMachine) AND !(wix.WixUISupportPerUser)</Publish>
        <Publish Dialog="WelcomeEulaDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="WelcomeDlg" Order="2">1</Publish>
        <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="WelcomeDlg" Order="2">1</Publish>

        <InstallUISequence>
            <Show Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Before="WelcomeEulaDlg">Installed AND PATCH</Show>
            <Show Dialog="WelcomeEulaDlg" Before="InstallScopeDlg">NOT Installed</Show>
            <Show Dialog="InstallScopeDlg" Before="ProgressDlg">NOT Installed</Show>
            <Custom Action="WixSetDefaultPerUserFolder" Before="CostFinalize" />
            <Custom Action="WixSetDefaultPerMachineFolder" After="WixSetDefaultPerUserFolder" />
            <Custom Action="WixSetPerUserFolder" After="WixSetDefaultPerMachineFolder">ACTION="INSTALL" AND APPLICATIONFOLDER="" AND (ALLUSERS="" OR (ALLUSERS=2 AND (NOT Privileged)))</Custom>
            <Custom Action="WixSetPerMachineFolder" After="WixSetPerUserFolder">ACTION="INSTALL" AND APPLICATIONFOLDER="" AND (ALLUSERS=1 OR (ALLUSERS=2 AND Privileged))</Custom>

        </InstallUISequence>

        <Property Id="ARPNOMODIFY" Value="1" />
    </UI>

    <UIRef Id="WixUI_Common" />
</Fragment>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at my open source project ISWIX (CodePlex).   It includes a multiple project solution template that includes a project for building the MSI.  It adds a reference to WiXUI and uses a series of fragments to reference a built in dialog set and then one additional reference to insert a custom dialog into the set.   This is done by adding Publish elements (DoAction ControlEvents) to the Next and Back buttons of the neighboring dialogs.  All of this is achieved in a way that feels as close to inheritance as possible.

http://iswix.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#main/Source/Application/IsWiXAddIn/MSISolutionTemplate/SetupProjectTemplate/UI.wxs

http://iswix.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#main/Source/Application/IsWiXAddIn/MSISolutionTemplate/SetupProjectTemplate/UI-CustomDialog.wxs

Also, be very sure you really want to support per-user installations.  They are a pain to deal and only valuable in limited scenarios.

https://web.archive.org/web/20170518122755/http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Add-install-InstallScopeDlg-to-WixUI-InstallDir-wxs-td7588647.html

Comment: PainterAll custom dialogs are working in Next and Back buttons.Except the installScopeDlg..!!! How to work with this InstallScopeDlg..?