# WixUi Change install directory not working

Tags: installation, wix, wix3

I am using Wix Toolset to create an installer for my application, I very new to the technology.

I need to be able to able to install on a per user and per machine bases, per user to install in the `%LOCALAPPDATA%` folder and per machine in `PROGRA~1`.

I have tried to follow [this](https://wixtoolset.org//documentation/manual/v3/wixui/dialog_reference/wixui_advanced.html) example from Wix Toolset with no luck.

I have also tried to set up my own Interface (parts of which taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22254945/wix-ui-customization-adding-installscopedlg-to-wixui-minimal) post) which is not over writing the install folder:

```
<UI Id="UserInterface">

  <Property Id="WixUI_Mode" Value="Custom" />
      
  <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Normal" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="8" />
  <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Bigger" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="9" Bold="yes" />
  <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Title"  FaceName="Tahoma" Size="9" Bold="yes" />

  <Property Id="DefaultUIFont" Value="WixUI_Font_Normal" />

  <DialogRef Id="InstallScopeDlg"/>
  <DialogRef Id="ProgressDlg" />
  <DialogRef Id="ErrorDlg" />
  <DialogRef Id="FilesInUse" />
  <DialogRef Id="FatalError" />
  <DialogRef Id="UserExit" />

  <Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="InstallScopeDlg">1</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="InstallScopeDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="WelcomeDlg">1</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="InstallScopeDlg" Control="Next" Property="WixAppFolder" Value="{}" Order="2">WixAppFolder = "WixPerUserFolder"</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="InstallScopeDlg" Control="Next" Property="WixAppFolder" Value="1" Order="3">WixAppFolder = "WixPerMachineFolder"</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="InstallScopeDlg" Control="Next" Property="ALLUSERS" Value="{}" Order="4">WixAppFolder = "WixPerUserFolder"</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="InstallScopeDlg" Control="Next" Property="ALLUSERS" Value="1" Order="5">WixAppFolder = "WixPerMachineFolder"</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="InstallScopeDlg" Control="Next" Property="INSTALLFOLDER" Value="[WixPerUserFolder]" Order="6">WixAppFolder = "WixPerUserFolder"</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="InstallScopeDlg" Control="Next" Property="INSTALLFOLDER" Value="[WixPerMachineFolder]" Order="7">WixAppFolder = "WixPerMachineFolder"</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="InstallScopeDlg" Control="Next" Event="EndDialog" Value="Return">1</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="ExitDialog" Control="Finish" Event="EndDialog" Value="Return">1</Publish>

</UI>
```

Regardless of which scope I select during the installation, the installer attempts to write the files to the `PROGRA~1` folder.

My guess at the moment is the `<Directory Id="ProgramFiles64Folder" />` is forcing the installer to use the Program Files folder, which requires elevated privileges. I have tried `<Directory Id="INSTALLATIONLOCATION" />` instead which moved the installation to ProgramData, also tried applying the `ConfigurableDirectory` attribute to my feature which does not work.

My Product.wxs config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Product Id="{GUID}" Name="My App" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Company" UpgradeCode="{GUID}">
    <Package InstallerVersion="301" Compressed="yes" InstallPrivileges=""/>

    <WixVariable Id="WixUIBannerBmp" Value="Images\Banner.bmp" />
    <WixVariable Id="WixUIDialogBmp" Value="Images\Dialog.bmp" />

    <WixVariable Id="WixUISupportPerMachine" Value="1" />
    <WixVariable Id="WixUISupportPerUser" Value="1" />

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." AllowSameVersionUpgrades="yes" />
    <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />

    <PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK45"/>
    <Property Id="ARPPRODUCTICON" Value="icon.ico" />
    <Property Id="ApplicationFolderName" Value="My App" />
    <Property Id="WixAppFolder" Value="WixPerUserFolder" />

    <Icon Id="icon.ico" SourceFile="Icon.ico"/>

    <!-- Check for .NET version -->
    <Condition Message="This application requires .NET Framework 4.5.2 or higher. Please install the .NET Framework then run this installer again.">
      <![CDATA[Installed OR NETFRAMEWORK45]]>
    </Condition>

    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Merge Id="VCRedist" SourceFile="Microsoft_VC141_CRT_x64.msm" DiskId="1" Language="0"/>
      <Directory Id="ProgramFiles64Folder"> <!-- Is this the problem, how can I make this configurable depending on user selection?-->
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="My App" />
      </Directory>
      <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
        <Directory Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder" Name="Company"/>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>

    <DirectoryRef Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder">
      <Component Id="ApplicationShortcut" Guid="{GUID}">
        <Shortcut Id="ApplicationStartMenuShortcut" Name="My App" Target="[#App.exe]" WorkingDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER"/>
        <RemoveFolder Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder" On="uninstall"/>
        <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\Company\My App" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes"/>
      </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>

    <Feature Id="VCRedist" Title="Visual C++ Runtime" AllowAdvertise="no" Display="hidden" Level="1" >
      <MergeRef Id="VCRedist"/>
    </Feature>

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="My App" Level="1">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="MyFiles" />
      <ComponentRef Id="ApplicationShortcut" />
    </Feature>

    <UI Id="UserInterface">
      <!-- see above -->
    </UI>

    <UIRef Id="WixUI_Advanced" />
  </Product>
```

I am clutching at straws and cannot find any solid examples or documentation to solve the Directory. How can I set the installation folder to `%LOCALAPPDATA%` or `PROGRA~1` depending on the selection within the Installation Scope?

Answer (score 0):

There are three properties to control the default install scope when using WixUI_Advanced UI: 'ALLUSERS', 'Privileged' and 'MSIINSTALLPERUSER'.

The property 'WixAppFolder' will control which radio button is selected by default when 'advanced' button is clicked.

And there is a konwn bug of wix needs a workaround: https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/2376

In summary, the wix config can be:

- Per user

  <Property Id='WixAppFolder' Value='WixPerUserFolder' />
  <Property Id='ALLUSERS' Value='2' />
  <Property Id='Privileged' Value='0' />
  <Property Id='MSIINSTALLPERUSER' Value='1' />
  <UI>
      <UIRef Id='WixUI_Advanced' />
      <UIRef Id='WixUI_ErrorProgressText' />
      <Publish Dialog='InstallScopeDlg' Control='Next' Property='MSIINSTALLPERUSER' Value='1' Order='3'>WixAppFolder = "WixPerUserFolder"
      <Publish Dialog='InstallScopeDlg' Control='Next' Property='MSIINSTALLPERUSER' Value='{}' Order='2'>WixAppFolder = "WixPerMachineFolder"
      <Publish Dialog='InstallScopeDlg' Control='Next' Event='DoAction' Value='WixSetDefaultPerMachineFolder' Order='3'>WixAppFolder = "WixPerMachineFolder"
      <Publish Dialog='InstallScopeDlg' Control='Next' Event='DoAction' Value='WixSetDefaultPerUserFolder' Order='3'>WixAppFolder = "WixPerUserFolder"
  </UI>
- Per machine

  <Property Id='WixAppFolder' Value='WixPerMachineFolder' />
  <Property Id='ALLUSERS' Value='1' />
  <Property Id='Privileged' Value='1' />
  <Property Id='MSIINSTALLPERUSER' Value='0' />
  <UI>
      <UIRef Id='WixUI_Advanced' />
      <UIRef Id='WixUI_ErrorProgressText' />
      <Publish Dialog='InstallScopeDlg' Control='Next' Property='MSIINSTALLPERUSER' Value='1' Order='3'>WixAppFolder = "WixPerUserFolder"
      <Publish Dialog='InstallScopeDlg' Control='Next' Property='MSIINSTALLPERUSER' Value='{}' Order='2'>WixAppFolder = "WixPerMachineFolder"
      <Publish Dialog='InstallScopeDlg' Control='Next' Event='DoAction' Value='WixSetDefaultPerMachineFolder' Order='3'>WixAppFolder = "WixPerMachineFolder"
      <Publish Dialog='InstallScopeDlg' Control='Next' Event='DoAction' Value='WixSetDefaultPerUserFolder' Order='3'>WixAppFolder = "WixPerUserFolder"
  </UI>

BTW, I created a project to simplify the configuration of wix. Hope it can help: https://github.com/xinnj/WiXCover